# What is the ^^^ operator in Scala?

Tags: scala, operators

I have seen in some Scala code the use of `^^^` and don't understand its use, nor can see any documentation about it. Also I'm pretty sure it doesn't come from any external library, but it may be the case, maybe ? I know that `^^`  is an operator for `.map()` but don't know if there is a similarity when you had a third ^.

Example of use :

```
case object TypeFoo extends Type {
    override def toString() = "Foo"
}
case object TypeBar extends Type {
    override def toString() = "Bar"
}
def repType= (
    "Foo" ^^^ TypeFoo
    | "Bar" ^^^ TypeBar
)
```

From what I may understand it could be "is defined by", but I'm really not sure, hence my question.

Comment: It's not standard as far as I know, but in Scala you can create your own operators, so it must be from some kind of library. Can you show imports?

Comment: Oh I see. Those are the two imports :
```import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical.StandardTokenParsers```
```import scala.util.parsing.input._```

Comment: Avoid `scala.util.parsing`. They are not supported, use non-standard naming, they are slow and buggy. Use something like fastparse or atto, which are maintained and safer to use.

Comment: I would strongly recommend staying away from scala-parser-combinators. It's outdated, buggy and extremely slow. Atto or fastparse are much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javadoc for the `^^^` method says:

> A parser combinator that changes a successful result into the specified value.
>
> `p ^^^ v` succeeds if `p` succeeds; discards its result, and returns `v` instead.
>
> `@param v` The new result for the
> parser, evaluated at most once (if `p` succeeds), not evaluated at all
> if `p` fails.
> `@return` a parser that has the same behaviour as the
> current parser, but whose successful result is `v`

In other words, `"Foo" ^^^ TypeFoo` is just a shorthand for `"Foo" ^^ (_ => TypeFoo)`.